# Find force on the disc due to hinge at its centre when the particle reaches the highest point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

> A uniform circular disc of mass $M = 4\,\text{kg}$ and radius $R = 25\,\text{cm}$ is suspended in a vertical plane and hinged at its centre 'O'. It is free to rotate about a horizontal smooth and fixed axis passing through its centre and perpendicular to its plane. A particle of mass $m = 0.5\,\text{kg}$ moving horizontally with a velocity $u = 20\,\text m/\text s$ collides with disc at point 'P' and gets stuck to it as shown. ($g = 10\,\text m/\text s^2$). Find force on the disc due to hinge when particle is at it's highest point
>
> [image]

By using conservation of angular momentum and energy, angular velocity was
$\omega = 8\,\text{rad}/\text s$ initially and $\omega = \sqrt{56}\,\text{rad}/\text s$ when the particle reaches highest point.

My solution matched till this point. After this in the solution
$$(M+ m) g - F = (M + m)\omega^2R/9$$

$F = 38\,\text N$ (vertically upward) here $F$ is the force due to hinge.

Why was centripetal force divided by 9 here? I didn't include it and my answer came out to be $18\,\text N$ vertically downwards.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time posting so your edit really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you have made here is that by considering the centripetal force as (M+m)Rw², you considered that a mass m and another mass M are moving on the circular path.

But here it is not the case, M is the mass of the disc and the COM of the disc coincides with the axis of rotation that is the reason why (M+m)Rw² is wrong. Also another way to see it is that Mg and mg if considered separately do not act at the same point.

Now about the factor 9: As the disc is rotating and there is a mass on it rotating, effectively their centre of mass is rotating on a circle with the radius r=mR/m+M which comes out to be R/9 and therefore the centripetal force becomes (M+m)Rw²/9.

Hope this helps, if yes, please upvote